# How to center prints with Octoprint and Prusa Mini?

Tags: octoprint, prusa-mini

Octoprint is printing in the top right corner of my Prusa Mini. What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the wrong dimensions set in PrusaSlicer, under **Bed Shape**:

[image: Screenshot of the Bed Shape window in PrusaSlicer showing previous settings]

I needed to change **X** and **Y** to 180:

[image: Screenshot of the Bed Shape window in PrusaSlicer showing corrected settings]

Comment: Indeed a slicer error, not a print server error. OctoPrint Just prints where you have sliced it.